# How WPF Converters are executed?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, converters

I'm facing render issues in very complex WPF UI which contains, among other things, a lot of Converters (IValueConverter, IMultiValueConverter).

I would like to know if the converters could be involved into this.

Does anyone known how WPF Converters worked ?
Are they executed in parallel and then synchronized with the UI thread ? or is there some kind of foreach loop that treat every converter ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The converters are executed on the UI-thread, you can test this by blocking the thread using something like `Thread.Sleep(10000)`. The UI is managed in a dispatcher queue, see the [threading model reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx) for more information, updates to bindings are pushed into that queue. Converters are called if the binding was updated, they normally are not being called at the same time.

*(Also see the good comments below)*

Comment: +1, Nicely worded.  I'd also like to add that if you have a converter that takes a long time to execute it will block the UI since yes, it is on the UI thread.

Comment: +1, good explanation. As a side note: converters are executed on the UI thread *even if the binding is asynchronous* (IsAsync=True). The property value is retrieved asynchronously from the source, then the converter is executed synchronously on the UI thread.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: I tought about adding this as it is not intuitive at all, good point.

Comment: +1 For the very informative answer and excellent (and interesting) reference to the threading model.