# Multi-Thread a Style DataTrigger IValueConverter in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, datatrigger, ivalueconverter

I am conditionally formatting a listview by setting the Style DataTrigger and binding it to an IValueConverter (CheckForShade) which returns  if the styling should be applied.

```
<Style.Triggers>       
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CheckForShade}}" Value="false" >
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

The problem is that the logic contained in the IValueConverter is pretty intensive and I would like someway to to multi-thread it so that each row in the Listview can be evaluated for formatting at the same time and in a thread other than the UI thread.

Also it currently slows the application from opening while it checks all the rows of the Listview and applies formatting, I would like to delay the formatting check until the UI has loaded and then multi-thread each row.

Comment: Converters are run in the UI thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865912/how-wpf-converters-are-executed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using a binding with `IsAsync` set to `true`, and then specify a fallback value of false: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.isasync.aspx.

Alternatively, a `PriorityBinding` with your CheckForShade converter with the highest priority and a default binding that returns `false` with a lower priority: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.prioritybinding.aspx
The benefit of the `PriorityBinding` is that it keeps listening for property changes for bindings higher in the list. This way you could implement your converter like this:

- Create a worker thread to calculate your boolean values and put them in a static dictionary.
- Implement your converter to see if the result is ready (using `TryGetValue` on the dictionary, for example).
- If the result is ready, return it. Otherwise, return `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`.